# Fake It Easy - A<T>.Ignored() with string - A<string>.Ignored()

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

I've a method with a string parameter and a bool return value.
I want to ensure that it always returns true

I tried

```
myClass.Foo(A<string>.Ignored)
 .WithReturnType<bool>()
 .Returns(true);
```

Now I get the following exception

> System.ArgumentException: The specified object is not recognized as a
>   fake object. Result StackTrace:    bei
>   FakeItEasy.Core.DefaultFakeManagerAccessor.GetFakeManager(Object
>   proxy)    bei FakeItEasy.FakeFacade.GetFakeManager(Object fakedObject)
>   bei FakeItEasy.Configuration.FakeConfigurationManager.CallTo(Object
>   fakeObject)    bei FakeItEasy.A.CallTo(Object fake) [...]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You don't show us how you make `myClass`. Is it an instance of your class? It should be a fake. And the syntax is off.

Consider this example usage from the [FakeItEasy tests](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/blob/984ba059c1d4cc70127cefe78318eb79bdac002f/Source/FakeItEasy.IntegrationTests/ConfigurationTests.cs):

```
var foo = A.Fake<IFoo>();
A.CallTo(() => foo.Baz(null, null)).WithAnyArguments().Returns(99);
```

So your example would likely end up being something like

```
var myClass = A.Fake<MyClass>(); // or maybe IMyClass - if Foo isn't 
                                 // virtual, you'll have problems faking it
A.CallTo((() => myClass.Foo(null)).WithAnyArguments().Returns(true);
```

Or `() => myClass.Foo(A<string>.Ignored)`, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to go for the short form which is in its completeness (as Blair Conrad says)

```
var myClass = A.Fake<MyClass>(); // or maybe IMyClass - if Foo isn't 
                                 // virtual, you'll have problems faking it
A.CallTo((() => myClass.Foo(A<string>.Ignored)).Returns(true);
```

you can replace `A<string>.Ignored` by `A<string>._` which are equivalent but the latter is more readable